# Fullcalendar settings from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

Is it possible to set the following setting of Fullcalendar.js from mysql, or some file?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        allDaySlot: true,
        allDayText: 'Celý den',
        firstHour: 8,
        slotMinutes: 30,
        defaultEventMinutes: 120,
        defaultView: 'resourceDay',
        axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
        timeFormat: {
            agenda: 'H:mm{ - h:mm}'
        },
        dragOpacity: {
            agenda: .5
        },
        minTime: 8,
        maxTime: 18,

        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,resourceDay'
        },
        ..
```

i need that user can edit it through interface which i make.

Comment: do you want to use any server side language such as php?

Comment: ofc, sorry that i forget to say it. I want to use php to do it.

Comment: Then it should be as simple as storing and retrieving the values from mysql.Then `echo` them inside javascript,like `echo "allDayText: '$value'";`